# WordPress htaccess redirect wild redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I am using WordPress WooCommerce.

My product links are like this: `http://example.com/product/tshirt123`

How do I code the `htaccess` so my links will be redirected to `http://example2.com/product/tshirt123`?

Currently I have this code below in my `htaccess` but it doesn't redirect
`http://example.com/product/tshirt123` to `http://example2.com/product/tshirt123`.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteRule ^product\/?(.*)$ "http\:\/\/example2\.com\/product$1" [R=301,L]
```

How should I change so it will redirect
links like:

`http://example.com/product/tshirt123` to
`http://example2.com/product/tshirt123`?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Do you need to redirect all the URLs of the site or just products alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add this to the top of your '.htaccess' file and NOT after WordPress default rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(product)/(.*)$ http://example2.com/product/$2 [R=301,L]
```