# WordPress htaccess image redirect

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have two WordPress websites that are exactly the same but one has no images at all.

Site that has no images: `http://example.com`

Site that has many images: `http://example2.com`

How do I code the htaccess so that `http://example.com` will use all the images at `http://example2.com`?

Comment: Duplicate of [WordPress htaccess redirect wild redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51451001/wordpress-htaccess-redirect-wild-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule wp-content/uploads/(.*) http://example2.com/wp-content/uploads/$1 [NC,L]
```

If there is no file, redirect to second domain.